# save in simple table and many-to-many relationship table in one transaction Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server

Hello I have table in MS SQL for example:

```
Employee(
id int primary key identity(1,1),
firstName nvarchar(50),
lastName nvarchar(50),


)

and many-to many relationship table

    ordersEmployee(
    id int primary key identity(1,1)
    order_id int foreign key references order(id),
    employee_id int foreign key references employee(id),
   )
```

I'm using entity framework and I want to save new employee in Employees table and that's employee's id in ordersEmployee table in single transaction how could i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SaveChanges` creates a transaction. If you have to call `SaveChanges` twice (or more) you can use a `TransactionScope`

```
using(var tx = new TransactionScope())
{
    // ...
    context.SaveChanges();
    // ...
    context.SaveChanges();

    tx.Complete();
}
```

Comment: and how can i get the primary key of an employee after I call the first saveChanges?

Comment: EF fills the `Id` property automatically after calling `SaveChanges`. But you don't need to know the `Id` to create the relation. Add the Employee, add an order to its Orders property and call `SaveChanges`. EF should save everything.